# Running iOS simulator on Windows by Connecting to MAC

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, ios-simulator

I'm trying to run ios Simulator on Windows, I successfully connected to the MAC, but there's no devices I could run on. How can I run ios simulator on this thing and please bear with me I'm new to this? [image]

Comment: can your try disconnecting and re connecting mac. my mac some time face the same problem
also check if xcode and vs is properly installed on your mac

Comment: I've tried disconnecting and reconecting mac, and yes both xcode and vs are installed. Btw, my VS version is 2017 on both Windows and MAC

Comment: choose iPhone instead of iPhoneSimulator in combo

Comment: @JeePakaJP selecting Iphone will give him list of connected iphones but he want to use simulator

Comment: did you tried creating a demo xamarin project on you mac and try to access simulator in mac ?

Comment: updated I restarted my laptop and I got list of iphone now,but I'm getting an error '
no valid ios code signing keys found in keychain. you need to request a codesigning certificate

'

Comment: i think you need a certificate from developer account but for testing i thing it can work if you do fallowing steps 

right click on IOS project go to properties->iOS bundle signing and select automatic provisioning

Comment: What I'm trying to do is run ios simulator via Xamarin and run react-native ios on it. Is it possible?

Comment: Go to tools-->options-->Xamarin-->Apple account to config your apple account and  certification there. BTW,Xamarin and react-native ios are two totally different things.